# Is it possible to use codespaces + local mysql server?

Tags: mysql, database, integration

I'm using a local mysql server alongside a spring boot application, it's easy to configure the MySQL server in the application properties file:

```
spring.datasource.username=blablabla
spring.datasource.password=blablabla
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

- Now I want to use the local Mysql Server with the Spring boot
  application that's running on codespaces.
- Is this possible? if so,
  how?